# How can I use ctypes to pass a byteArray into a C function that takes a char* as its argument?

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have created a function in C which takes an int size and a char *buffer as arguments. I would like to use ctypes to call this function from python and pass in a python byteArray. I know that first you must compile the C file into a shared library (.so file) and use ctypes to call that function. Here's the code I have so far.

encrypt.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void encrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer);
void decrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer);

void encrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        unsigned char c = buffer[i];
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
void decrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        unsigned char c = buffer[i];
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

And here's the python file:

```
import ctypes

encryptPy = ctypes.CDLL('/home/aradhak/Documents/libencrypt.so')
hello = "hello"
byteHello = bytearray(hello)
encryptPy.encrypt(5,byteHello)
encryptPy.decrypt(5,byteHello)
```

Basically I want to call the C method from python, pass through a python byte array, and have it iterate through the array and print each element

Answer (score 17):

Mark's answer is quite helpful in that it passes a character array to the C function, which is what the OP really wanted, but in case there's folks finding their way here who really want to pass a byte-array, [an approach seems to be to build a ctypes.c_char backed by the memory of your byte-array, and pass that](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-January/563875.html).

My example here disregards the argument declaration recommend by Mark, which indeed seems like a good idea.

```
import ctypes

# libFoo.c:
# (don't forget to use extern "C" if this is a .cpp file)
#
# void foo(unsigned char* buf, size_t bufSize) {
#   for (size_t n = 0; n < bufSize; ++n) {
#     buf[n] = n;
#   }
# }

fooLib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib/libFoo.dylib')

ba = bytearray(10)

char_array = ctypes.c_char * len(ba)

fooLib.foo(char_array.from_buffer(ba), len(ba))

for b in ba:
  print b

# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
```

Comment: Unfortunately the link takes to a different topic. But thank you for the code anyway - it seems to work (though I am not sure that there's no memory allocated when char_array is assigned to initially.

Comment: TLDR: Convert your byte array to a char array with `(ctypes.c_char*len(ba)).from_buffer(bytearray(ba))`, where `ba` is your byte array.

Comment: TLDR: In Python 3 just use`bytes(ba)` (for immutable buffer) or `create_string_buffer(bytes(ba))` (for mutable).

Comment: @Mark `create_string_buffer(bytes(ba))` makes a copy of the data and therefore doesn't apply the modifications to the underlying `ba`.

Comment: @JaySullivan `(ctypes.c_char*len(ba)).from_buffer(bytearray(ba))` creates a copy of your bytearray (which makes it equivalent to Mark's answer). The correct TLDR is `(ctypes.c_char*len(ba)).from_buffer(ba)`

Answer (score 6):

The minimum you need (Python 3) is:

```
hello = b"hello"
encryptPy.encrypt(5, hello)
encryptPy.decrypt(5, hello)
```

But it is best practice to declare the argument types and return values as well so `ctypes` can perform argument type checking.  Full program:

```
#!python3
import ctypes as ct

encryptPy = ct.CDLL('/home/aradhak/Documents/libencrypt.so')    
encryptPy.encrypt.argtypes ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p
encryptPy.encrypt.restype = None
encryptPy.decrypt.argtypes = ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p
encryptPy.decrypt.restype = None

hello = b"hello"
encryptPy.encrypt(len(hello), hello)
encryptPy.decrypt(len(hello), hello)
```

Note that when passing a Python byte string, consider the buffer immutable.  In this case you only are reading the buffer, but if you need to allow the C function to mutate the string use:

```
hello = ct.create_string_buffer(b'hello', 5)
```

Below works as well, but will be length 6.  A terminating null will be included.

```
hello = ct.create_string_buffer(b'hello')
```

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you. for the python-ignorant out there in the future, if your C function takes only a single argument, specify `argtype` as `[ctypes.some_type]` rather than as `(ctypes.some_type)`. the latter is apparently interpreted as a single item rather than a list containing a single item.

Comment: @orionelenzil try `(ctypes.some_type,)` with a comma

Comment: @osvein Parentheses aren’t needed except for clarity for order of operations. `.argtypes = c_int,` works. The comma makes it a tuple.