# How to increment a character pointer in C without segmentation fault error?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

So I have the following function defined in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void encrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer){
    buffer[i] = buffer[i] + 1;
    printf("%c",buffer[i]);
}

int main(){
    encrypt(5,"hello");
}
```

I'm expecting this to return `ifmmp`, but instead I get the error

> "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

If I get rid of the line
`buffer[i] = buffer[i] + 1`
and
`printf("%c",buffer[i]+1)`
then I get the desired result. But I would like to actually change the value stored in that address. How can I do this?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: "hello" is a const readonly data you can't increment it since it's not a variable.  Try using character array instead.

Comment: Turn on *all* your compiler warnings.

Comment: I believe this is a runtime error, since it only comes up when I try and run the program. So when I say "gcc -o test test.c" everything's good. But when I say ./test then I get that error.

Comment: Dont pass `"hello"` as it is a string literal and a  constant . Use `char s[]="hello";` as suggested by @cleblanc .

Comment: There's a code smell in there, what's `size`, not used. What's `i`, not used either. Back to drawing board there I guess.

Comment: Enclose a proper [MCVE] to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @cleblanc Then why can I say "printf("%c", buffer[i] + 1) and have it print "ifmmp"?

Comment: Because your above commented code is not *altering a string literal*. It is showing each character + 1.

Comment: @Mr.Pickles That `printf` statement is correct no problem in that , but this is what creates probe - `buffer[i] = buffer[i] + 1;` because you modify `buffer[i]` here . There is difference between `buffer[i]+1` and `buffer[i]=buffer[i]+1` (_latter one tries to modify literal_).

Comment: "buffer[i] = buffer[i] + 1" is not incrementing a pointer. It is trying to set a character in "buffer" equal to the following character in "buffer". which character it is trying to change depends on the value of "i".

Comment: There is **undefined behaviour** being induced with side effect of seg faulting, `i` is uninitialized, and could be referencing an out of bounds outside of the buffer by incrementing it to something else, and printing garbage.

Comment: The "segmentation fault" is because you are trying to change the character at "buffer[i]", but it is a unwritable constant.

Comment: Where does `i` come from?

Comment: Yes, `i` is uninitialized in above code. And BTW you must use a loop to achieve desired result. And what's the point of sending `size` as an argument to `encrypt()`?

Comment: is this code related to OP's previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422662/how-can-i-use-ctypes-to-pass-a-bytearray-into-a-c-function-that-takes-a-char-as) and [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423867/how-can-i-use-java-native-interface-to-pass-a-byte-array-into-a-c-function-which) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489128/i-have-2-very-similar-c-functions-being-called-from-python-and-java-how-can-i-c) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code :

- `i` is uninitialized
- `"hello"` is converted to `int`, so avoid sending that way. instead see the code bellow
- you've sent argument `size` but haven't used it.
- finally, use a loop to increment every value in the array `char *buffer`
- return a value at the end of `main()` as you mentioned return type as `int`

So, here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void encrypt(int size, char *buffer){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        buffer[i] =(buffer[i]+1);
    printf("%s",buffer);
}

int main(){
    char s[]="hello";// total 5 charcters + '\0' character
    encrypt(5,s);
    return 0;
}
```

the output generated is as desired.

Comment: Well, two out of four isn't terrible, I suppose. And did you *compile* this, or are you leaving the task of discovering a `char[5]` can't possibly hold "hello" (hint: nulchar terminator?) as an exercise to the OP?

Comment: Yes I compiled @WhozCraig do you mean I mentioned only 2 problems?

Comment: @WhozCraig i updated my answer, i think it has no issues now.. And BTW thanks for mentioning th null character issue

Comment: @Mr.Pickles if you have any doubts regarding my code, you can ask me